# Update Android module

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

I am building a new android application which has multiple modules.I have a module for analytics which will have the changes quite frequently.Is there any way I can update this module without pushing an app update. I am open to write this module in Java/kotlin/React-native. I know that React native has [Codepush](https://microsoft.github.io/code-push/) but for this also I need to push an update for my app. Dynamic modules also do not solve my problem as they do not support the individual module updates. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Android studio you can publish an application using the webview method.
This way you can update quickly from the outside.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_webview.htm